# Inline For Loop for algorithmic package

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

Using algorithmic package I would like to have an inline for loop.
Currently I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
        \begin{algorithmic}
        \FOR{k=1}
        \STATE{$k=k+1$}
        \ENDFOR
        \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Which produce the for loop in three line, while I would like to have all on one line. I saw this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/algorithmic-put-if-and-endif-into-same-line), but could not adapt to the For loop. Any help appreciated.