# Algorithmic: Put If, Else and EndIf into the same line

Tags: algorithmic

I am reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/algorithmic-put-if-and-endif-into-same-line) post how `\If{cond} \State{statement} \EndIf` can be placed in the same line. Could you please someone suggest a way on how `\If{cond} \State{statement} \Else \State{statement} \EndIf` can be placed in the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```tex
\algnewcommand{\ElseIIf}[1]{\algorithmicelse\ #1}
```

then input

```
\IIf{$x_1 = 0$} $x_z = 10$ \ElseIIf{$x_z = -1$}\EndIIf
```

will generate output

[image]

Full example, based on Werner's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184228

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[Algorithmus]{algorithm}
\algnewcommand{\IIf}[1]{\State\algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}
\algnewcommand{\ElseIIf}[1]{\algorithmicelse\ #1} % <<< added
\algnewcommand{\EndIIf}{\unskip\ \algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Inline if-then-else}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \IIf{$x_1 = 0$} $x_z = 10$ \ElseIIf{$x_z = -1$}\EndIIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note: see `\IIf` and `\EndIIf` defined in other post; have suggested an edit to the answer.

Comment: @rrrrr Thanks for your suggested edit. I decided to add a full example.